# How to fix the recursion problem in jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have been on a game project for a while. I have used bootstrap and jQuery. But to keep it simple, here is what the piece of code in which I did not understand anything looks like. I wanted that by clicking and only clicking on item A, item B will show and disappear after clicking on it. I added an instruction that will show me after every click on an item a message in the console and watch what happens!

```js
let elt_boxOne = $("#bx_one");
let elt_boxTwo = $("#bx_two");
elt_boxTwo.hide();

elt_boxOne.click($.proxy(function() {
  elt_boxTwo.show();
  elt_boxTwo.click($.proxy(function() {
    console.log("Hello world");
    elt_boxTwo.hide();
  }, this));
}, this));

/*As you can see the first time has no problem but if we try the second time there will be two messages and the third click will show three etc... I mean what the hell is going on???*/
```

```css
#bx_one {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#bx_two {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: orange;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="bx_one">Box one</div>
<div id="bx_two">Box two</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning a click-event-handler inside a click-event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736271/assigning-a-click-event-handler-inside-a-click-event)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing the click listener to many times, when you click on button 1. You have to move it outside, independent of the first click handler... like this:

BTW, you don't need proxies, you can use arrow functions if you need the context inside.

```js
let elt_boxOne = $("#bx_one");
let elt_boxTwo = $("#bx_two");

elt_boxTwo.hide();

elt_boxOne.click(() => {
    elt_boxTwo.show();
});

elt_boxTwo.click(() => {
    console.log("Hello world");
    elt_boxTwo.hide();
});
```

```css
#bx_one {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#bx_two {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="bx_one">Box one</div>
<div id="bx_two">Box two</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not create your "box 2" listener inside of your "box 1" listener. Simply separate the two element's click handlers.

```js
const
  $boxOne = $("#bx-one"),
  $boxTwo = $("#bx-two").hide();

$boxOne.on('click', () => $boxTwo.show());

$boxTwo.on('click', () => {
  console.log("Hello world!");
  $boxTwo.hide();
});
```

```css
.bx {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#bx-one { background-color: red; }
#bx-two { background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bx-one" class="bx">Box one</div>
<div id="bx-two" class="bx">Box two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes the code I gave is simple ... But it does not perfectly illustrate my problem. In fact in my original code this is a dialog box that pops up when I click on a button, and this dialog box contains a "confirm" button. I want that when I click on the confirm button (Unlike the display of "hello world" in the console in this code) a confirmation message goes from the dialog box to the object that contains the first button that I clicked. So i told myself that the two click events must be connected. i could be wrong

Comment: Please do not use answers for anything other than answers to the question. Stack Overflow is not a forum; it is a strict question and answer site. If you have more information to add to your question, edit your question to include it.